# How to convert html to string include img tags android

Tags: javascript, android, html

How to convert html to string include images tags in android?

I have a text in textview like : **Hello world!{an image} I am here!{an image}**

html code of this text is :

`<div>Hello world!</div><br><img src=foo><div>I am here!</div><img src=foo>`

I want convert to this text to string like this :

`Hello world!<img src=foo>I am here!<img src=foo>`

remove all tags except `<img>`

help me...

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java String method ‘replaceAll’, which will replace all strings matching a given set of strings (first parameter, e.g string1|string2|string3) with a new String (second parameter).

In your case:

```
String input = textView.getText().toString();
String result = input.replaceAll("<div>|</div>|<br>", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution :

```
String subbed = postcontent.replaceAll("< *[iI][mM][gG]", "_iimmgg");
String stripped = android.text.Html.fromHtml(subbed).toString();
String result = stripped.replaceAll("_iimmgg", "<img");
```